# wpf ViewBox - when scaling a DataGrid, the Grid lines are missing

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF Toolkit DataGrid control, contained within a Grid, inside a ViewBox control.  The DataGrid has its own style with Black background, White Text and White Grid lines.

Some of the **grid lines are missing from the grid** (literally) from display, typically when there are 10 rows or more in the DataGrid.  When I remove the ViewBox, it works fine (but I need scaling hence the use of the ViewBox).

I have not set many properties of the viewbox:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both">
```

Do I need to set other properties in order for the DataGrid to be scaled properly?  Or because the DataGrid has its own customized style?

Thanks very much

Joe

Comment: Can you post some xaml that reproduces this behavior? It seems to work find for me

Comment: Thanks Meleak, it is now Fixed.  It was a case of increasing the Border size of the DataGridCells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increased the Border size of the DataGridCells in the DataGrid Customized style.